# Position on specific div on content load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, object, pageload

I'm developing a Angularjs frontend with a Node.js backend where I can received all the data. I get an array of json objects who represents several dates like this:

```
[
 ...
 {date: "30/11"}, /* today */
 {date: "1/12"},
 {date: "2/12"},
 {date: "3/12"},
 ...
]
```

I would like to display the array like this but the first day on the actual view should be "today" and be able to scroll left/right to display older/newer days.

```
+----------------------------+
| today   1/12   2/12   3/12 |
|+-----+ +----+ +----+ +----+|
||     | |    | |    | |    ||
||     | |    | |    | |    ||
|+-----+ +----+ +----+ +----+|
|                            |
|         Scrollbar          |
| <________________________> |
+----------------------------+
```

Actually I display the array from the start with ng-repeat. I'm able to detect "today" with a comparison and add a class to the specific div BUT I don't know how to align the screen on the "today" div. Do you have any idea about how I can do this ?

Comment: Do you have *yesterday* as well in your response ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `scrollIntoView()`.

Here's a sample. The `scrollIntoView` should be in the a directive. I've put it in the controller just to show how it's supposed to work.

**Script**

```
angular.module("app", []).controller("LineCtrl", function ($scope) {
    var tds = []
    for (var i = 0; i < 250; i++)
        tds.push(i);

    $scope.tds = tds;

    setTimeout(function () {
        document.getElementsByClassName('today')[0].scrollIntoView();
    }, 1000)
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="LineCtrl">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td ng-repeat="td in tds" ng-class="{ 'today': $index === 50 }">{{ td }}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**Code Snippet**

```js
angular.module("app", []).controller("LineCtrl", function($scope) {
  var tds = []
  for (var i = 0; i < 250; i++)
    tds.push(i);

  $scope.tds = tds;

  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementsByClassName('today')[0].scrollIntoView();
  }, 1000)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="LineCtrl">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="td in tds" ng-class="{ 'today': $index === 50 }">{{ td }}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks it works well ! One more thing, do you know how I can align the scroll on the left of my container ? I tried with some function such as scrollLeft or offsetWidth but the result is not perfect..

Comment: Do you a fiddle for your code. It'd be easier to tinker with it than set up a new one :-)